# Event posted multiple times on AsyncEventbus

Tags: java, spring, guava, spring-aop, event-bus

In my setup I have customized `Guava`s (version 24.1) `AsyncEventBus` slightly:

```
public class PausableAsyncEventBus extends AsyncEventBus implements IPausableEventBus{
    private boolean paused = false;
    private LinkedList<Object> queuedEvents = new LinkedList<>();

    public PausableAsyncEventBus(Executor executor, SubscriberExceptionHandler subscriberExceptionHandler) {
        super(executor, subscriberExceptionHandler);
    }
    public void pause() {
        paused = true;
    }
    public void resume() {
        paused = false;
        while (!paused && !queuedEvents.isEmpty()) {
            super.post(queuedEvents.removeFirst());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void post(Object event) {
        if (!paused) {
            super.post(event);
        } else {
            queuedEvents.add(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a task that is executed once which posts an event. The `AsyncEventBus` is injected by `Spring` dependency injection:

```
@Autowired
private AsyncEventBus clientServerEventBus;

public void run() {
    log.info("Run CelebrationTask for "+ this, new Exception("Called from"));
    // calculate number of guests
    CelebrationState state = calculateCelebrationState();
    TargetedDialogStateWrapper wrapper = new TargetedDialogStateWrapper(player, state);
    clientServerEventBus.post(wrapper);
    // update reputation
    updateReputation(state);
}
```

I have an AOP aspect defined on the post method, so I can log what events are posted. This post here results in these lines:

```
2018-12-27 23:52:53,783 [pool-2-thread-4] INFO  c.s.g.o.c.l.EventBusAspect : Posted event on event bus 'PausableAsyncEventBus (default)' ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.ui.TargetedDialogStateWrapper 35645f14-e0d9-40f0-aa1e-e1c6f99e8d43: Thomas Pfeffersack from ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.clientserverinterface.model.task.CelebrationTask.run
2018-12-27 23:55:03,212 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO  c.s.g.o.c.l.EventBusAspect : Posted event on event bus 'PausableAsyncEventBus (default)' ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.ui.TargetedDialogStateWrapper 35645f14-e0d9-40f0-aa1e-e1c6f99e8d43: Thomas Pfeffersack from ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.clientserverinterface.model.task.CelebrationTask.run
2018-12-27 23:55:08,215 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO  c.s.g.o.c.l.EventBusAspect : Posted event on event bus 'PausableAsyncEventBus (default)' ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.ui.TargetedDialogStateWrapper 35645f14-e0d9-40f0-aa1e-e1c6f99e8d43: Thomas Pfeffersack from ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.clientserverinterface.model.task.CelebrationTask.run
2018-12-27 23:55:13,218 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO  c.s.g.o.c.l.EventBusAspect : Posted event on event bus 'PausableAsyncEventBus (default)' ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.ui.TargetedDialogStateWrapper 35645f14-e0d9-40f0-aa1e-e1c6f99e8d43: Thomas Pfeffersack from ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.clientserverinterface.model.task.CelebrationTask.run
2018-12-27 23:55:18,303 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO  c.s.g.o.c.l.EventBusAspect : Posted event on event bus 'PausableAsyncEventBus (default)' ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.model.ui.TargetedDialogStateWrapper 35645f14-e0d9-40f0-aa1e-e1c6f99e8d43: Thomas Pfeffersack from ch.sahits.game.openpatrician.clientserverinterface.model.task.CelebrationTask.run
```

The log line on the run method only appears once, so I know that the run method is only called once, but the event is posted multiple times over multiple threads. This in turn causes multiple handling of the same event.

The essential part of my aspect looks like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public void com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(Object))")
public void syncEventBus(){}

@Pointcut("execution(public void com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(Object))")
public void asyncEventBus(){}

@Before("syncEventBus() || asyncEventBus()")
public void logEvent(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object event = joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
    if (!ignore(event)) {
        String name = ((EventBus) joinPoint.getTarget()).identifier();
        StringBuilder sb = ...
        log.info(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

I just do not see where it goes wrong. It could be something todo with the aspect or the fact that the eventbus is proxyed by Spring, or something completely different, I cannot think of. Any ideas?

[EDIT:]
Note that the first two log entries are on different threads and some minutes apart, all following are on the same thread as the second and only seconds apart. However between those log lines, there are also other logged events, that were cut out for simplicity.

[EDIT2:]

I found the cause. In the handler method that is `@Subscribe`d to the event I have:

```
executor.schedule(() -> clientServerEventBus.post(new TargetedEvent((IHumanPlayer) player, wrappedDialogState)), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

With `wrappedDialogState` being the event object.
Then I have another method that subscribes to `TargetedEvent`:

```
@Subscribe
public void propagate(TargetedEvent message) {
    clientServerEventBus.post(message.getEvent());
}
```

This will of course call the first event handler, which will post a new message after 5 seconds.

Is there any way I can create an architectural test that checks for such event loops?

Comment: Style comment: Your code would be easier to understand if you used an instance of AsyncEventBus in a class which implements IPausableEventBus but doesn't extend anything -- i.e. use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Just guessing, but post() gets called twice (once on your subclass, once on AsyncEventBus) and there are two identical point cuts which match it (why?) so that's four calls to logEvent.

Comment: @tgdavies: That could be part of the problem, but then there should only be two logged statements and both of them for the same thread...

Comment: Some debugging suggestions: 1. Try matching just the call to post on your class in your point cut, and remove the redundant point cut. 2. Print a stack trace in your logEvent method so you can see where it is being called from. 3. Subscribe to the EventBus and see how many events the client gets.

Comment: Actually -- each of your last four events is almost exactly 5 seconds apart.